# String trimmer lines, What types and whats best?

Tags: string-trimmer

I know about the different shapes for string trimmer (weed wacker) like square and round and all the others. But there is plastic and nylon and stuff like that. I have a 0.065" size trimmer and deal with fairly thick weeds. What should I get and what should it be made of? I would rather not have to buy a new weed wacker that uses bigger string, I love my Ryobi!

Comment: Could you improve the title of question (now it is too broad). "Thick weeds" is also too generic (and not really objective). What are the problems with you actual string? (Maybe a photo could help).  Also the power of your string trimmer is important to select the maximum size (and weight) or strings.

Comment: My string trimmer is a Ryobi 18v battery powered trimmer. Max. size is 0.065". I do not know about the weight. As for the string I have round plastic. It wears off rather thick in the thick grass and I want to know if there was another material that did better. From below I think I will give the Star shape a try.

Answer (score 2):

For any line trimmer, I think, one can get a different head other than the bump and go.  Gotta wear glasses and be on your toes about where you send rocks and other stuff that can kill, blind or bust out windows.  Those shields help but they actually cause more harm because we think they are protecting us from flying rocks. Bump and go heads with shields are like bicycles and training wheels.  Can't see what the heck you are doing and make one pretty complaisant to danger and effectiveness.

Just go ask for a stationary head that fits your trimmer. One cuts off sections of line to fit and then threads them through the head.  Once it gets too short one just simply replaces the line.  Make sure the line is absolutely equal.  To do that turn the wacker upside down and trim your line on concrete or a big rock.  You'll hear the difference in sound...it'll go grrrrrrrrr at a lower tone and then rise...can't figure how to type it, grins.  You'll know.  Equal lengths are vastly easier on your motor and vastly more effective.  Hey, longer is not better.

I like the star shape, doesn't last as long but is viciously effective.  DID I SAY WEAR SAFETY GLASSES?  And gotta remind one when using gas powered equipment (the only ones to use in my opinion, not electric whimpy stuff) WEAR EAR protection as well.  I had to fire guys that would go around the corner and take their glasses, ears off.  I had two of those idiots lose an eye apeice.  Man, did I get pissed and no one ever heard the end of my admonitions!!  Dumb and dumber.  Like, I'd sit for hours until the idiots of my guys got their seatbelts on...most of my guys were brilliant and understood. sighs.

There are other tools for thicker weeds to include a mower looking gismo that easily knocks down chews up bramble and woody shrubs.  Another is a small blade instead of line that will take down 4" caliper trees.  Always use the right tool for the job or risk injury, ruining your equipment and/or looking like an idiot.  Grins!!  Hey, I considered going into a weed wacker competition, I think I know what I am talking about!!  Grinning widely!